# How to reduce the size of msi installer?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm converting msi package that was written with wix# to wix.

The difference between the 2 packages is almost 100MB.
The logic is the same and all the files are the same.

How to reduce the size of the new msi package?

Is there more options than this option?
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371150(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [CompressionLevel](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/media.html) for the Media node.

Comment: My final package size reduced by 15%. Thanks